# XML Reading out Nested Content

Tags: java, xml, jsp, opencms

Lets say i have the following Structure

```
<xmlsheet>
    <someContent>
        <directContent>hello</directContent>
        <otherDirectContent>hello again</otherDirectContent>
        <nestedContent>
            <title>Hello im a Title</title>
        </nestedContent>
    </someContent>
    <someOtherContent></someOtherContent>
</xmlsheet>
```

**How do i select the title  of nestedContent in someContent?**

When i select the directContent in someContent it works like this

```
        <cms:contentaccess var="content" />
        <c:set var="directContent" value="${content.valueList.someContent[0].value.directContent}"/>
```

If i only say `${content.valueList.someContent[0].value}` it will throw out direct and otherDirect content but not the nested content :<

Comment: Try `${content.valueList.someContent[0].value.nestedContent.value.title}`

Comment: Doesnt throw an error but also doesnt give me the title > doesnt work

Comment: Let's try another one: `${content.valueList.someContent[0].value['nestedContent/title']}`

Comment: That one works! But why? Is there any guide for reading out XML

Comment: I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code `${content.valueList.someContent[0].value['nestedContent/title']` works. It uses the xpath to the value.
From the [documentation](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Cms:contentaccess)

> Map:getValue()
>
> Returns a lazy initialized Map that provides values from the XML content  in the current locale. The provided Map key is assumed to be a String that represents the **xpath** to the value.

See also the underlying [Java API](http://documentation.opencms.org/javadoc/core/org/opencms/jsp/util/CmsJspContentAccessBean.html#getValue%28%29)